# Fluid loss in 2.83

Tags: fluid-simulation

My fluid simulation is a rotating cube filled with water. I noticed, that the volume of the water gets less and less while the cube is moving, but there is no fluid escaping from the cube.
During my research, I have found this problem with earlier versions of Blender and the Flip Fluid addon. Version 2.80 had an option to compensate this effect called "Impact factor" (see: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/physics/fluid/types/obstacle.html).
In version 2.83 I cannot find this option anymore.

Here (https://github.com/rlguy/Blender-FLIP-Fluids/issues/436) it was stated that the problem is related to fluid particles sticking to the sides of the obstacle.

Does anyone know, how to fix this? Is this on the bug list?

Thanks for your help!
Mick